# replace with a new string if text contains a specific character in r

Tags: r, string

> I have a list of strings in R which looks like:

```
amor
amores
enamorado
enamorar
```

> I want to replace with the word amor, all strings that start and containts this letter. the result should look like:

```
amor
amor
enamorado
enamorar
```

> It´s important to notice that the word enamorado contains the letter amor. I´m trying to do this with:

`data$word<-gsub("amor.*", "amor", data$word)`

> but the result is

```
amor
amor
enamor
enamor
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `^` to indicate the beginning of your string pattern.

```
vec <- c("amor", "amores","enamorado", "enamorar")

gsub("^amor.*", "amor", vec)
# [1] "amor"      "amor"      "enamorado" "enamorar"
```

Comment: if speed is taken into consideration, then `sub` would be better than `gsub`

Answer (score 1):

A non-regex base R solution would be with `startsWith` which returns a logical value indicating if a string starts with a particular prefix or not. Using @www's data.

```
vec[startsWith(vec, 'amor')] <- 'amor'
vec
#[1] "amor"      "amor"      "enamorado" "enamorar"
```